# javascript - select a div within a particular div

Tags: javascript

The content of the divs is going to be populated with javascript json. Now, I know how to select a div in javascript:

```
var hsc = document.getElementByID("hsc");
```

But how would I refer to eg. the title but only in the hsc div.

```
<div id="hsc">
    <div id="title"></div>
    <div id="jobs"></div>
...
</div>

<div id="cc">
    <div id="title"></div
    <div id="jobs"></div>
</div>
```

On a separate note, wouldn't 'title' and 'jobs' be better classified as classes, and not ids?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. The `id` attribute must be unique. Use the `class` attribute if you wish to have multiple elements containing the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work:

```
var hsc = document.querySelectorAll("#hsc > .title");
```

But you need to change to valid html and use unique IDs and classes instead:

```
<div id="hsc">
    <div class="title"></div>
    <div class="jobs"></div>
...
</div>

<div id="cc">
    <div class="title"></div>
    <div class="jobs"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

IDs must be unique in HTML.

Change them to classes, and then you can use [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to target them:

```js
document.querySelector('.hsc .title').style.color= 'blue';
document.querySelector('.cc .title').style.color= 'red';
```

```html
<div class="hsc">
    <div class="title">Make me blue!</div>
    <div class="jobs">Jobs</div>
</div>

<div class="cc">
    <div class="title">Make me red!</div>
    <div class="jobs">More jobs</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try

```
<div id="hsc">
    <div id="a" class="title"></div>
    <div id="b" class="jobs"></div>
...
</div>

<div id="cc">
    <div id="c" class="title"></div
    <div id="d"class="jobs"></div>
</div>
```

Because your HTML code is invalid because the id is already taken.